# How to get the device token in iOS 10 if user does not accept to receive Push Notifications?

Tags: ios10, devicetoken

I had my app for iOS 9 implementing `application(_:didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:)` that gets invoked whether or not user accepts to receive Push Notifications, hence I get and store on the remote server the device token in both cases.

Now with iOS 10 this delegate method never gets called if user does not accept to receive Push Notifications... Is there any other way to get the device token in such a case?

Answer (score 0):

You can't. If user doesn't accept notifications, you can't get any token for this.

Comment: Can I use this: `UIDevice.current.identifierForVendor!.uuidString` to get a unique identifier for the device? I need to identify each device as this is the way the remote db is structured!

Comment: You can, but remember that this id changes in many certain situations. See documentation

Answer (score 0):

This is the fact when user not accept to receive notification then application will not generate `device token` or sometime by mistake click on `don't allow` option, so whenever you want to need app required Push notification need to show any `popup(Alert view) message` there for why you need `push notification` access inside app then `second time` give some `tutorial/advice/guidance` for how user  `enable` manually `push notification` service from **iOS** device `Setting option`.